# why processTicksAndRejections() task_queues.js#L67 spending significant time on cpu

Tags: node.js

One of my nodejs application performing heavy load work at a given time where more than 4/5 requests being processed by nodejs . Each of these requests contain, http & DB exit calls which are performing well in ms. However, if I check the flame graph https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/5fad0b93667ffc6e4def52996b9529ac99b26319/lib/internal/process/task_queues.js#L67 , this specific code from a node is utilizing 70% of CPU time.

I am wondering if I can insight into these internal functions of node and understand the technicality of these methods in order to understand the current bottleneck.

> 1)https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/5fad0b93667ffc6e4def52996b9529ac99b26319/lib/internal/process/task_queues.js#L67
> 2)https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/5fad0b93667ffc6e4def52996b9529ac99b26319/lib/internal/process/promises.js#L220

Answer (score 0):

`processTicksAndRejections()` is the entry point of microtasks so if your async workload takes a lot of time this method will have significant *total time* too. It's better to diagnose the problem by checking the paths with the most *self time* from the profiler instead.